# WD Passport -PN :WDBKXH5000AWT-01

Tags: windows-7

After installing Windows 7 64-bit, my Western Digital Passport drive is being detected, but I cannot see a drive to open it.

I checked the drive on another system and it works, but not on mine.
I have installed the driver on my PC as well.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Open Disk Management (`Start / Run / diskmgmt.msc`), right-click the drive and assign drive letters to it as required.